# Why is a rational divisor class on $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$ determined by its values on families not mapping into a given subvariety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces

This question is about Exercise 3.90 on page 143 of the book "Moduli of Curves" by Harris & Morrison.

To avoid defining stacks, the authors define a "rational divisor class on the moduli stack" to be an association $\gamma$ to each family $\rho:\mathcal{X}\to B$ of stable curves of a rational divisor class $\gamma(\rho)\in\mathrm{Pic}(B)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ such that for any map $\beta:B'\to B$, $\gamma$ assigns to the pullback family $\rho':\mathcal{X}'=\mathcal{X}\times_B B' \to B'$ the rational divisor class $\gamma(\rho') = \beta^*(\gamma(\rho))$. They denote the group of rational divisor classes on the moduli stack by $\mathrm{Pic}_\text{fun}(\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g)$.

Exercise 3.90 comes shortly after. The first part of the exercise is to show that any rational divisor class on the moduli stack $\gamma\in \mathrm{Pic}_\text{fun}(\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g)$ is determined by its values $\gamma(\rho)$ on families $\rho:\mathcal{X}\to B$ with smooth, one-dimensional base $B$. I'm not actually sure exactly how the fact that $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$ is singular might complicate this, but I'm not so worried about that. The second part of the exercise is where I'm a bit worried. It says to show that, given any proper subvariety $\Sigma \subset \overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$, any rational rational divisor class on the moduli stack $\gamma\in \mathrm{Pic}_\text{fun}(\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g)$ is determined by its values $\gamma(\rho)$ on families $\rho:\mathcal{X}\to B$ with smooth, one-dimensional base, and such that the image $\varphi(B) \subset \overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$ under the induced map $\varphi:B\to \overline{\mathcal{M}}_g$ isn't contained in $\Sigma$.

It would be very helpful if someone could briefly explain this exercise. Say you have a family over a curve which "witnesses" the non-triviality of the class $\gamma$, but which unfortunately maps into $\Sigma$ -- how do you perturb this family away from $\Sigma$ while preserving the property that it is a witness?

Comment: The thing I would try would be to embed the curve base of this family into a surface, with a family of curves over that surface, and then find another, rationally equivalent, curve in the surface. Of course there are many details to check...

Comment: It is indeed possible that such a curve class cannot be perturbed away from $\Sigma.$ But what does happen is that such a curve class will be the difference of curve classes that can be perturbed away. In the setting that Will mentions (surfaces), you can do this by adding a sufficiently large multiple of an ample divisor.